# Load scene with modified setting?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I load a scene with a modified setting?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your code seems legit. What happens, if you try it..?

Comment: @ThomasHilbert Current **pseudo**-code has no effect.

Comment: What do you mean by "modified setting"? Do you get any errors, like NullPointerException?

Comment: Since we don't know what you want to modify, we can't really tell, what you have to do. If you want to hide/unhide some objects for example, you would do something like you did in your snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change some properties of an object based on the actual level, you can check for the actual level using [Application.loadedLevel](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-loadedLevel.html). An example based on your code:

```
void Awake() {
    DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
}

void Start(){
    if (Application.loadedLevel == 1){
        GameObject.Find("object1").GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
    }
    else{
        //Other actions...
    }
}
```

I hope to having understood your issue properly.

Comment: Where do I attach this script? On the initial scene or on the loaded scene?

Comment: Scripts are not attached to scenes. You can attach it to an object that will persist across the scenes. As an example, create an empty object with no render at all, and attach this to it. I edited the code to include the persistency (DontDestroyOnLoad).

Comment: It should make use of SceneManager instead of Application.loadedLevel. And this is kinda wrong design since your object is persistent and you place the scene check in Start. Would be more suitable in OnLevelWasLoaded.